# If a time range in to different cells is between a range return "YES"

Tags: excel

I have time 05:35 in one excel cell and 22:30 in another. I want to find out how many hours and minutes that falls between the time 06:00-22:00 and how many hours that falls after 22:00 and before 06:00

Try this link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JzsN77RIHYJKCsM0jRR0DkY4TR2pfCjsqVKiFOgrGI/edit#gid=0

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JzsN77RIHYJKCsM0jRR0DkY4TR2pfCjsqVKiFOgrGI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Doesn't really seems to work. Ideally I want the formula to bring me how many hours that are between to times. For instance:

Cell A1 "05.00" cell B1 "23.00". Outcome of the formula should be "times between 06.00-22.00". So in this case it should be 16. In below case the outcome should be 1.

Cell A2 "07.00" Cell B2 "08.00" Please see link to better understand. Cant attached images. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JzsN77RIHYJKCsM0jRR0DkY4TR2pfCjsqVKiFOgrGI/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `MROUND` function to round up or down to the nearest hour.  Alternatively, replacing the "1:00" can round to 30 minutes ("0:30"), or other intervals.

So, if you have in your destination cell:
`=MROUND(B2, "1:00")-MROUND(A2, "1:00")` into Cell `C2`, it should round for you successfully and show the difference.

Remember to replace `B2` with your oldest time cell, and `A2` with your earliest time cell.

EDIT: Here's a shot of your Google Docs sheet, with the formula modified to be a 'time' and correctly showing the expected results.

[image]

Comment: Thank, see you point now. And from this, how do I change so only the value between 06:00am to 22:00pm shows in the formula column, i.e. if its a shift from 06:00-22:30, I want it to show 8 hours, not 08:30 (or 8.5h hours) since I pay my staff different based on what hours they work. See same link:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JzsN77RIHYJKCsM0jRR0DkY4TR2pfCjsqVKiFOgrGI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Subtract 0:30 from all of the values at the end of the formula, and then drag down.  If this correctly solved your issue, please mark as accepted using the checkmark as well.